# Adding a object to an array of object

Tags: reactjs, redux, react-redux

My app is using react, redux and redux-thunk.  I want to add a new product to `https://fakestoreapi.com/products`. The code below works, so I am happy with that, but it adds a single stringe. I want it to add a object of key-value pairs like that:

```
   title: 'test product',
                price: 13.5,
                description: 'lorem ipsum set',
                image: 'https://i.pravatar.cc',
                category: 'electronic'
```

My code:

```
import React from "react";
export const ProductForm = ({ addProduct }) => {
  const [product, setProduct] = React.useState("");

  const updateProduct = (event) => {
    setProduct(event.target.value);
  };

  const onAddProductClick = () => {
    addProduct(product);
    setProduct("");
  };

  return (
    <div>
      <input
        onChange={updateProduct}
        value={product}
        type="text"
        name="title"
        placeholder="title"
      />
      <button onClick={onAddProductClick}>Add product</button>
    </div>
  );
};
```

I know that i have to use a form to do this task. Although I don't know how to change the code below so that it woudl still works. If in form `onSubmit` i use same function as `onClik` in code above, the page refresh itself and do not add a product to an array.

Answer (score 0):

You are setting product to the value from the input here:

```
  const updateProduct = (event) => {
    setProduct(event.target.value);
  };
```

event.target.value is a string. It's whatever you enter in your input.

If you want an object you can:

1. change product to productName and use productName in onAddProductClick. Like `addProduct({title: productName})`

OR

2. change updateProduct to:

   ```
   const updateProduct = (event) => {
    setProduct({title: event.target.value});
   };
   ```

Comment: Yeah, thanks for this. But accualy i want to make a form, because i want to add multiple data at once so as title,price, description etc..

Comment: ok so repeat what you did for product title